# Getting a particular value from QuerySet in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

how can I get to print "Mathematics" from this QuerySet?

```
<QuerySet [<Schedule: Thursday - Class 1/2/3 Section A - Mathematics>]>
```

Comment: can you share some more details ?? what exactly you want

Comment: please update your question, with details and your model

Comment: so here is my tuple present in models.py
SUBJECT = (
        ('eng', "English"),
        ('hin', "Hindi"),
        ('mat', "Mathematics"),
        ('sci', "Science"),
       )

and when i import the class containing this tuple in my views.py and print it, it gives me that above mentioned query set and i want to show that last value that is the subject on my front end template but idk how to extract only subject part that is "Mathematics" in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by:

```
for schedule in Schedule.objects.all():
    print(schedule.subject)

# or
print(Schedule.objects.values_list('subject', flat=True))  # print a list of subjects

# or
print(Schedule.objects.values('subject'))
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values).